# Finding OPF packet with instruction to remove flow due to idle timeout expiration

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow

I'm using the single topology with openvswitch-testcontroller, so the command to launch mininet is: *sudo mn --topo=single --controller=remote,127.0.0.1:6653*

I traced communication between switch and controller. After pinging h2 from h1, for the FLOW_MOD OPF messages I detected that the **idle timeout was set to 60 sec**.

The next series of pings was later (after 60 sec were passed), and there were PACKET_IN messages from switch due to no match - it means that the previous flow matching the pattern (pinging h2 from h1) was removed.

But I **can't find the packet which instructs the switch to remove the flow due to timeout expiration**! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch removes the flows after their expiration time, no need to get a packet for this.

From [Openflow official documentation](https://3vf60mmveq1g8vzn48q2o71a-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-switch-v1.3.5.pdf): (5.5 Flow Removal part)

> The switch flow expiry mechanism that is run by the switch
>   independantly of the controller and is based on the state and
>   configuration of flow entries. Each flow entry has an idle_timeout and
>   a hard_timeout associated with it. If either value is non-zero, the
>   switch must note the flow entry's arrival time, as it may need to
>   evict the entry later. A non-zero hard_timeout field causes the flow
>   entry to be removed after the given number of seconds, regardless of
>   how many packets it has matched. A non-zero idle_timeout field causes
>   the flow entry to be removed when it has matched no packets in the
>   given number of seconds. The switch must implement  flow expiry and
>   remove flow entries from the flow table when one of their timeout is
>   exceeded.